# Navigation to master page while clicking on Image placed in details page in master details page

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using master details page in xamarin.forms for iOS application,there I have placed an image in top  left corner ,now I would like to navigate to master page on clicking on that image,how to get it to be navigated.

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MasterApp.Controls;assembly=MasterApp"
             x:Class="MasterApp.Views.Dashboard.MasterDetailPage">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Padding="10" Title="Master" >

        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <ContentPage Icon="Menu Icon.png">
            <ContentPage.Content>

            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Here I need to go master page while clicking on icon in details page.

Comment: If I mean you want to open menu master detail after image click?

Comment: Yes exactly @qubuss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some workaround and finally made it to be navigated to master.

```
 <MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MasterApp.Controls;assembly=MasterApp"
                 x:Class="MasterApp.Views.Dashboard.MasterDetailPage">
        <MasterDetailPage.Master>
            <ContentPage Padding="10" Title="Master" >

            </ContentPage>
        </MasterDetailPage.Master>

        <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
            <ContentPage>
                <ContentPage.Content>
     <Image Source="Menu.png"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>                      
                    </Image>
                </ContentPage.Content>
            </ContentPage>
        </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    </MasterDetailPage>
```

In cs,I written

```
private async void TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            IsPresented = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set icon in the XAML where you have your master layout. And only here you set the icon. Please look at the [official xamarin tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/)

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         x:Class="MasterDetailPageNavigation.MasterPage"
         Padding="0,40,0,0"
         Icon="hamburger.png" // here you set icon for navigation 
         Title="Personal Organiser">
<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="listView" SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="5,10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

===EDIT===
Try to move `Icon` to `MasterDetailPage` and maybe it will be problem with name of image icon. Because if your name have whitespace it can be problem.

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MasterApp.Controls;assembly=MasterApp"
         x:Class="MasterApp.Views.Dashboard.MasterDetailPage"
         Icon="Menu Icon.png">
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Padding="10" Title="Master" >

    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <ContentPage Icon="Menu Icon.png">
        <ContentPage.Content>

        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Comment: Thanks for help @qubuss,I tried placing icon but no luck,I updated my code can you please guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: I did as like you qubuss  but no result,its not navigating to master by clicking on icon.

Comment: So maybe try to write code from official tutorial and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the Icon and tap it to navigate to the master page. We should embed a NavigationPage to wrap your ContentPage like:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <ContentPage>
                <ContentPage.Content>

                </ContentPage.Content>
            </ContentPage>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Actually we can show the icon in master page, this is my whole code for you referring to:

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MasterDetailDemo.MyMasterDetailPage"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MasterDetailDemo">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Padding="10" Title="Master" Icon="Menu Icon.png">

        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <ContentPage>
                    <ContentPage.Content>
                       ...//add your control
                    </ContentPage.Content>
                </ContentPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```